# Cross reference target path for :func: :class: only paths from root work

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I'm a bit perplexed as to why my cross reference targets at not working correctly. Only full paths seem to work.  I have the following project structure:

```
my_project
-my_project
 -adapters
  -adapter_base
  -adapter_1
  -adapter_2
-docs
 -build
 -source
 -config.py
```

config.py

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

index.rst

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   modules/the_api
```

modules.rst

```
Adapter Base
------------
.. automodule:: my_project.adapters.base
   :members:
   :inherited-members:
   :show-inheritance:

Adapter 1
---------
.. automodule:: my_project.adapters.adapter_1
   :members:
   :inherited-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

adapter_1.py

```
class Adapter1(object):
   pass

class Adapter1API(object):
   def method_a(self):
        """the docs for this method_b"""
        pass

    def method_b(self):
        """the docs for this method

        This works :func:`my_project.adapters.adapter_1.method_a`
        No link :func:`method_a`
        No link :func:`.method_a`
        No link :func:`.adapter_1.method_a`
        """
```

As you can see in method_b i have tried 4 ways of creating a target path to method_a and only the full path works.  Any ideas why the other 3 are not?

Answer (score 2):

As embarrassing as this is, the solutions was `:meth:` NOT `:func:`  somehow i missed the fact that sphinx had a `:meth:` directive...